# Generate docker/config.json for AWS assumed role

Tags: amazon-web-services, assume-role

I am trying to push to a AWS registry (via Kaniko). In the registry account, there is a role `functional`, my account should assume. So I try to generate a `.docker/config.json` via:

```
set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail
export HOME=/root
mkdir -p "/root/.aws/"
cat <<EOF > /root/.aws/credentials
[functional]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::359685361593:role/functional
source_profile = default
[default]
aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
EOF
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true
export AWS_PROFILE=functional
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
docker_cmd=$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
url=$(echo "$docker_cmd" | sed -rn 's/docker login -u (.*) -p (.*) (.*)/\3/p')
auth=$(echo "$docker_cmd" | sed -rn 's/docker login -u (.*) -p (.*) (.*)/\1:\2/p')
auth=$(echo -n "$auth" | base64 -w 0)
cat <<EOF > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
{
  "auths": {
    "$url": {
      "auth": "$auth"
    }
  }
}
EOF
```

In the end, I get a `config.json` but it does not work.
Kaniko prints `status code 401; Not Authorized`.

Now I assume, that the role assuming failed somehow. But I have no idea, how get to a `config.json` with an assumed role.

Is there any way of debugging this or is there an easier way to do the role assuming?

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: Nope. We abandoned that idea.